# User data or profile on SE or SO

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts

A while ago I found a link that displayed all of the data about me collected by either Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow (I think it was one of the two). I can't find it now. Does anyone know of such a link?

I looked through my profile and several other places and can't find it. The list of data was huge, in JSON format I think. (It wasn't personal data, just site-related - how many posts I've made, questions I've read, etc., but a really big list.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that you're looking for your [personalized prediction data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data)?

Comment: is there a link from my user profile? or from http://stackoverflow.com/users ?